# Typescript complains when passing a possibly null (but not null) value to anonymous callback

Tags: typescript, vue.js, error-handling, vuex

When I have a property that initially begins as null, how can I pass this as an argument to an anonymous callback function that expects a non null value, without typescript complaining?

I can wrap my function call in an if statement to check for null, which stops typescript complaining at the function call level, but in the callback, typescript still complains.

Here's a snippet of the code. I allow some `DatabaseState` properties to be null, as this is how they are initialized.

```
//types.ts
export interface DatabaseState {
  db: PouchDB.Database | null;
  remoteDb: PouchDB.Database | null;
  dbReplication: PouchDB.Replication.Sync<{}> | null;
  dbSyncStatus: number;
  dbSyncInfo: string;
  dbSyncError: string;
}

//state typing - state: DatabaseState

//An action in database.ts
async startDatabaseSyncronisation({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
  var opts = { live: true, retry: true };

  if (state.remoteDb != null && state.db != null) {

    /* THE IF STATEMENT PREVENTS THE BELOW FUNCTION FROM CAUSING TYPESCRIPT TO COMPLAIN */

    await PouchDB.replicate(state.remoteDb, state.db, opts).on("complete",
      function(info) {

        /* WITHIN THE CALLBACK FUNCTION THOUGH, TYPESCRIPT COMPLAINS THAT state.remoteDb and state.db
        COULD BE NULL AND THE FUNCTION DOESN'T ACCEPT A NULL VALUE */

        let replication = PouchDB.sync(state.remoteDb, state.db, opts)
          .on("paused", function(err: {}) {
            dispatch("onSyncPaused", err);
          })
          .on("active", function() {
            dispatch("onSyncActive");
          })
          .on("denied", function(err: {}) {
            dispatch("onSyncError", err);
          })
          .on("error", function(err: {}) {
            dispatch("onSyncError", err);
          })
          .on("complete", function() {});
        commit(SET_DB_REPLICATION, replication);
      }
    );
  }
},
```

How should I approach these kinds of typing checks?
Is there a more "Typescript-friendly" way of describing an initial value as unset?

The project uses Vue, with Vuex for state management.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answers of @elderapo and @Andrew were useful.

@elderapo's answer most directly answered my intial query, that is "why does typescript not complain about the function call, but does complain about the callback?":

> The value of the state could change somewhere between the if check and complate callback

And @Andrew drew attention to the main issue, using null as a valid value in this case is probably unsafe.

> I would highly advise you always account for null. The concept of null was deemed to be a mistake and not protecting yourself against that value makes your code unsafe

Although I don't expect the value of `db` and `remoteDb` to revert to null between dispatching the action and the callback, it is better to remove this possibility altogether.
A lack of connection/loss of connection to the database is handled in other code.

Instead of allowing the type to be `null` simply for initialization, I now initialize them as empty objects with type casting.
Therefore I don't need to disable strictNullChecks (I want them).

New code:

```
export interface DatabaseState {
  db: PouchDB.Database;
  remoteDb: PouchDB.Database;
  dbReplication: PouchDB.Replication.Sync<{}>;
  dbSyncStatus: number;
  dbSyncInfo: string;
  dbSyncError: string;
}

const state: DatabaseState = {
  db: {} as PouchDB.Database,
  remoteDb: {} as PouchDB.Database,
  dbReplication: {} as PouchDB.Replication.Sync<{}>,
  dbSyncStatus: SyncStatus.NONE,
  dbSyncInfo: "",
  dbSyncError: ""
};


async startDatabaseSyncronisation({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
  var opts = { live: true, retry: true };
  await PouchDB.replicate(state.remoteDb, state.db, opts).on(
    "complete",
    function(info) {
      let replication = PouchDB.sync(state.remoteDb, state.db, opts)
        .on("paused", function(err: {}) {
          dispatch("onSyncPaused", err);
        })
        .on("active", function() {
          dispatch("onSyncActive");
        })
        .on("denied", function(err: {}) {
          dispatch("onSyncError", err);
        })
        .on("error", function(err: {}) {
          dispatch("onSyncError", err);
        })
        .on("complete", function() {});
      commit(SET_DB_REPLICATION, replication);
    }
  );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the state could change somewhere between the if check and `complate` callback. If you're sure the state hasn't changed you can tell the compiler to think that these values are not nullable by using [null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator): `state!.remoteDb`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, regarding changing before the callback is fired. I'll have to consider a safer way of initialising these database properties without resorting to null.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly advise you *always* account for `null`. The concept of `null` was deemed to be a mistake and not protecting yourself against that value makes your code unsafe. But if you insist, there is an option you can turn off your `tsconfig.json` called `strictNullChecks` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Should you even attempt a query if `remoteDb` or `db is`null`? Isn't that just going to break your code in runtime?

EDIT:
The function will just never run if either value is null? If that's the case, `replicate` and `sync` are incorrectly typed by the library. An oversight by the package authors then.

There's no "good" way to account for a fundamental mistake from a 3rd party. Easiest way to document this, but still keep typing is to create a `type` with a variable name to declare the reasoning. Maybe someone else has a better idea, but I would do this:

```js
type POUCH_BD_DATABASE_OR_NULL = PouchDB.Database

export interface DatabaseState {
  db: POUCH_BD_DATABASE_OR_NULL;
  remoteDb: POUCH_BD_DATABASE_OR_NULL;
  dbReplication: PouchDB.Replication.Sync<{}> | null;
  dbSyncStatus: number;
  dbSyncInfo: string;
  dbSyncError: string;
}
```

EDIT2:
If you are doing validations on `state` *before* it is passed into `startDatabaseSyncronisation`, then your typing that you are using for `startDatabaseSyncronisation` is fundamentally incorrect and you can't directly share `interface DatabaseState` between the two functions. The best you can do is the create an `interface` of the shared elements in both and then `extend` in the two interfaces.

```js
interface DatabaseMetaData {
    dbSyncStatus: number;
    dbSyncInfo: string;
    dbSyncError: string;
}

// for the function where it might be null
export interface DatabaseState extends DatabaseMetaData{
    db: PouchDB.Database | null;
    remoteDb: PouchDB.Database | null;
    dbReplication: PouchDB.Replication.Sync<{}> | null;
}

// for startDatabaseSyncronisation
export interface DatabaseSyncState extends DatabaseMetaData{
    db: PouchDB.Database;
    remoteDb: PouchDB.Database;
    dbReplication: PouchDB.Replication.Sync<{}>;
}
```

Comment: The action will only be dispatched if db and remoteDb are not null. That is why originally I didnt account for null in the action function. Would this be a situation where a null assertion opperator is useful?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I may have mislead you here. My own code that calls the startDatabaseSyncronisation() function checks that the value of db and remoteDb are valid connections to databases, prior to attempting to syncronise. PouchDB's sync and replicate methods don't accept null and will simply return an error if they receive invalid values. I believe they are correctly typed. Please may I have your comments on my solution in my answer.